# OctoberCMS scope not applying

Tags: eloquent, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

So the scenario here is that i'm trying to create a simple scope in OctoberCMS that will allow me to filter a query with the builder plugins list component. In my model I have defined the scope as such:

```
public function scopeFirst($query)
{
    return $query->where('practice_name',1);

}
```

This should just constraint the query to fetch only the records where that value is 1. The Component is recognizing this scope and allowing me to choose it from the drop-down list, as indicated by my index.htm file:

```
[builderList]
modelClass = "vetadmin\Practicedetails\Models\Practicedetails"
scope = "scopeFirst"
displayColumn = "id"
noRecordsMessage = "No records found"
detailsPage = "-"
detailsUrlParameter = "id"
pageNumber = "{{ :page }}"
```

Does anybody have any ideas of what could be causing it to not apply the constraint? Currently -all- the records are being returned. The documentation isn't particularly elaborate on this and just suggests you need to define the scope in your plugins model php file (as I've done)

https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#query-scopes

is the documentation i'm referring to.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think scope="scopeFirst" is correct, I think it should be scope="first"

Comment: Hi Luke, this returns a "Invalid scope method name." error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm this is little confusing for the `larval eloquent model`

> I have tested your code and scope

Then I just realised that `scopeFirst` can be apply on modal like this `$modal->first()` <= `this is issue its reserved method`

As per my knowledge `first` [ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent] is method to get first record from the `collection/models`. [ **So, your scope is treated like that and ended up doing nothing !** ]

> So, just change your scope name like `scopeFirstPractice` etc.. **can solve our issue**.

and just normally use

```
[builderList]
modelClass = "vetadmin\Practicedetails\Models\Practicedetails"
scope = "scopeFirstPractice"
```

It should definitely work. [ I have tested. ]

if any doubt please comment.